# how to make c# project with database independent of visual studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, nsis, projects

I made a Backup and restore project on visual studio , along with another project. They both use the default database of visual studio. They both have to bundled together along with the database, so it runs without Visual studio.  I have tried to use the default VS installer, but i don't think that allows me to use the database aswell.

I have decided to use NSIS to make the installer. What all files, libraries etc. do i need to make the database and project function together, independently(without visual studio). How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database do you mean? MS SQL or MySQL or another?

E.g. to create MySQL database from NSIS you can simply run command line utility and pass your sql script as parameter so the utility will create everything what is in the sql file.

Other database types simply need to extract their database file somewhere to disk and set appropriate paths.

Your question is very vague, there is more details needed to answer you.